# Trying to get dynamic links from database into my <img src="(link here)">

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display an image. I do this by fetching the link to the online image and passing it to a variable that then goes into the "src" of the `<img>` tag. I have tried doing this several ways, but nothing works.

I know how to make this work with folders and downloaded images, but I'd like to do this with online links. like google images.

NOTE: links are put into the database, and when I `print_r($plaatje)` it shows the actual link. but when I try to paste it into the HTML element, it doesn't work. I feel like I am making a simple mistake, but I can't find it.

```
    $plaatje_link = $connect->prepare("SELECT `plaatje_link` FROM `test`                 
    WHERE plaatje_id = 1");
    $plaatje_link->execute();
    $plaatje = $plaatje_link->fetch();

    array_shift($plaatje);
    implode($plaatje);
    ?>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <img src="<?php echo $plaatje ?>" alt="Ja, foto wil niet"/>
    </div>
```

P.S. the `array_shift` is there because for some reason it gives me the lik twicw. so with `array_shift` it removes one and leaves me with 1 value, which I need.

Comment: Could you use `print_r($plaatje)` and show us the results? (before using array_shift) - what about the implode? Also change `>` to `/>` when `<img>` closes

Comment: you can use a `LIMIT 1` at the end of the sql to just receive 1 entry.

Comment: Array ( [plaatje_link] => http://sm.askmen.com/askmen_nl/photo/default/pewdiepie-brofist-5ed8_znk8.jpg [0] => http://sm.askmen.com/askmen_nl/photo/default/pewdiepie-brofist-5ed8_znk8.jpg ) this is the result before the array_shift(). I am aware of the closing tags, makes no difference in this case. thank you

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos weird, for some reason the implode() doesn't have any function now. it was there to fix a array to string conversion error. but it seems that isn't the case anymore.. Odd.

Comment: can you specify the "it doesnt work" ? And what display your $plaatje variable after the implode ?

Comment: @Edwin i will do so! thank you for you input and time! I do appreciate it very much!

Comment: what is added in you 'src' attribute.You can check using inspect element in chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to either :

```
$plaatje = implode($plaatje); // convert it to a string ** for the specific example at least
```

Or Change

`<img src="<?php echo $plaatje ?>" alt="Ja, foto wil niet"/>`

To

```
<img src="<?php echo $plaatje['plaatje_link']?>" alt="Ja, foto wil niet"/> // or $plaatje[0]
```

Because you can't echo an array.

Answer (score 1):

`implode($plaatje);` works by value, not reference. The original array is not modified. So after this [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) operation `$plaatje` is still the array, not a string.

Also `->fetch()` has different modes, default being 'BOTH', meaning it will return the result as an array with both the numbered indexes as well as associative. See [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) for more info.

Comment: See also my update to the above answer regarding the 'double' entries in the original array.